# Expression in ng-model AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I need to execute an expression inside ng-model.

I have an array of integers which is shown in a list and input fields needs be generated on click of each item. All input fields should carry a generated value of ratio having base as 1. I also need to get the sum of numbers in the input field since the user can change the value.

[image: With 3 items selected and divided ratio]

[image: With 4 items selected and divided ratio]

My Code for this is

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="kpi in SelectedKpiModel">
    <div class="small-2 columns" ng-click="View.RemoveSelectedKPI($index)" style="margin-top:0.5em;border:ridge;padding-bottom: 1em; padding-top:0.5em; text-align:center"><span class="fa fa-scissors"></span></div>
    <div class="small-4 columns" style="margin-top:0.5em;border:ridge;padding-bottom: 1em; padding-top:0.5em; text-align:center">
        {{kpi.id}}
    </div>
    <div class="small-4 columns" style="float:left;margin-top:0.5em;border:ridge; padding:0em">
        <input type="number" value="{{1/SelectedKpiModel.length}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I get the count of all the field values if user changes or how do I store the value of each field and retrieve if need ?

I tried like `ng-model="{{1/SelectedKpiModel.length}}"` but it gave me error.

Thanks.

Comment: Can show us the error ? 
By the way if your length is 0 => https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

Comment: What does your controller look like? And `ng-model` is a two way binding, you can't use it for expressions like the above. If you need something like this, you must bind it to a [getter/setter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).

Comment: I do not have any error. I want to get the sum of all the fields. It can have 3 fields or 5 fields depend upon the selection. Can you help me to sum the value of all the input field values.

Comment: I am basically using the code given in https://jsfiddle.net/michaeldeongreen/22et6sao/9/ . My controller has this logic and with this my html generated text inputs.

Comment: Write a method in the controller that iterates the fields, adds the values and returns the sum. Then use it in your template eg: `{{getSum()}}`

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a user enters a change to one of the input fields?

Comment: @georgeawg :- I just want to sum all the field values and I will be alerting if that exceeds 1

Comment: @Mihai :- But in getSum function, how do I retrieve all the values in the input fields ?

Comment: @Joseph use an array of models, one for each input.

Comment: I used array of models. Now the problem is, the input fields are not changing the values on adding another field. It has the value set in its model. I want the input value to get changed on add/delete of rows.

Comment: Whenever an input is added/removed, you must calculate and update the value of the variables binded to ng-models

Comment: Using Model didn't helped me. What I have did is $scope.WeightedAverage = 0;
        $('#SelectedModelGrid input').each(function () {
            $scope.WeightedAverage += parseInt(this.value);
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this -

```
<input type="number" ng-model="getLength()" />
```

and your function -

```
$scope.getLength = () => {
    return 1 / $scope.SelectedKpiModel;
}
```